# Why does Integrate[] fail to give me an analytical expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying this integral to solve analytically, but *Mathematica* fails, and I get the integral back as it is defined. Although numerically it can be done, I need an analytical expression. Is there any way to get the analytical expression?

```
int[r_]= -((2.75516 r)/(Sqrt[-0.156567 + 0.4/r + 0.333333 r^2] (1.2 - 3. r + r^3)))
Integrate[int[r], r]
```

After Integration the generated output is

```
-2.75516 \[Integral]r/(Sqrt[-0.156567 + 0.4/r + 0.333333 r^2] (1.2 - 3. r + r^3)) \[DifferentialD]r
```

Comment: There might not be an analytical solution.

Comment: Earlier with some oter parametr choice, i got the analytical expression, I just change some values, to get that int[r]

Comment: The integrand is singular at two(?) points! What is the integration range?

Comment: 0.425719, 1.4795, these are the numerical limits.

Comment: In general, using approximate numbers (floating-point numbers like `0.333333`) in an exact solver like `Integrate[]` invites trouble: round-off error can cause exact algorithms to fail. (The transformations made by the solver assume there is no loss of precision.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An analytical expression.

```
$Version
(*"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"*)


func = Rationalize[-((2.75516 r)/(Sqrt[-0.156567 + 0.4/r + 
      0.333333 r^2] (1.2 - 3. r + r^3))), 0] // Factor; 
func2 = Apart[func]

(*(87142129092 Sqrt[(400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)/r])/(
11249986716267303599 (6 - 15 r + 5 r^3)) - (
183746368416132090 r Sqrt[(400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)/r])/(
11249986716267303599 (6 - 15 r + 5 r^3)) + (
68879 r^2 Sqrt[(400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)/r])/(
22499973432534607198 (6 - 15 r + 5 r^3)) - (
5809475272800000 Sqrt[(400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)/r])/(
11249986716267303599 (400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)) + (
1749963663521558798742 r Sqrt[(400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)/r])/(
1607140959466757657 (400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)) - (
3279949101 r^2 Sqrt[(400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3)/r])/(
16071409594667576570 (400000 - 156567 r + 333333 r^3))*)

INT = Integrate[#, r] & /@ (func2)

(*Very Large output*)
```

Comment: I am puzzling, because func2 is a real function between the two poles `{0.425719, 1.4795}` whereas `(INT /.r-> 1.4795)-(INT /.r-> 0.425719)` evaluates complex `60.6936 - 2.29196 I` . Am I making a thinking error? Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is becoming complex, as this is a time which actually I am getting, so I am interested n the real part.

Comment: @ImmySalam It's a real positive function, that's why the integral must be real!

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk What's your opinion concerning my comment to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann .Maybe `Mathematica` gives wrong answer.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you for your answer, I agree! I tried `D[INT,r]== func2` without success.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  #Mariuszlwaniuk. So should i rely on the numerical approach? Any further suggestions?

Comment: @ImmySalam Probably yes.

Answer (score 2):

If numerical result is sufficient  try:

First detect the singulatities in the integration range r>0

```
singu = r /.NSolve[ {Sqrt[-0.156567 + 0.4/r + 0.333333 r^2] (1.2 - 3. r +r^3) == 0, r > 0}, r]
(*{0.425719, 1.4795}*)
```

Numerical integration in the range `{r,0,R}`

```
int[R_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[-((2.75516 r)/(Sqrt[-0.156567 + 0.4/r +0.333333 r^2] (1.2 - 3. r + r^3))), {r, 0, R},Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> singu]

Plot[int[R], {R, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But the problem is that my integration limit, which you have kept as {R} have the lower and upper limits as these singularity points i.e {R , 0.425719, 1.4795 }. so it became an oscillatory there. If possible may you can figure it out.

Comment: @ImmySalam In that case the value of the integral probably  tends to `infinity`  I think!

Comment: No it is finite in that case, i got a plot but that is not smooth, you please check with those limits , can you get a better plot

Comment: @ImmySalam Why didn't you show these results "I got a plot..." ?

Comment: I used the same code, But after giving my limits , the plot is not smooth, there is noise in the graph